# .animate() in jQuery and if condition seems to don't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, jquery-animate

I'm not an expert in jQuery and I try to create a kind of button-toggle : 
When I click on the switch-button "Home/News", the content should switch too.

But that seems to don't work... Despite the if condition, the condition AND the else are executed... I don't get it. Someone can tell me where do I failed ?

Here is the jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/zgLsbw2h/1/

The jQuery :

`$(document).ready(function(){
    function switchButton(){
        console.log("coucou")
        $('.onoffswitch').click(function(){
            if($('.onoffswitch').hasClass('nothere')){
                $('.container_slide_actu').animate({
                    left : 0}, 700);
                $('.onoffswitch').removeClass('nothere');
            }else{
                $('.container_slide_actu').animate({
                    left : '-100%'}, 700);
                $('.onoffswitch').addClass('nothere');
            }
        });
    }
    switchButton();
});`

Thanks in advance.

**Edit

More explanation (in hope to simplify):

I have two html container. When I click on the button, I want to switch them. By default, I got the container1 ; when I click odd => container2 ; when I click even => container1...

Some screenshots to explain :

-The banner of my website (default => container1 (1 on the screenshot)) and the slideshow (who comes over the banner => container2 (2 on the screenshot)) : http://prntscr.com/dpwxat

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: Humm, I'll explain with some screenshots :
Here is the banner(from my website) : [link](http://prnt.sc/dpwm66)
When I click on the bottom-right button, i want this result : [link](http://prntscr.com/dpwn8i) 
(I need an "infinite loop" with this button ; I mean, when i click odd, banner, even, slideshow. I don't know if i'm clear)

I just want to change the content (with a kind of covering slide effect (that's why I need to use .animate() ?))

I use jQuery to achieve this result but, as you  can see in the jsfiddle, the animation executes the both effects (the in and the out in a way).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for your animation going in and out is because the onclick is running twice.  The reason for that is because you targeted the "onoffswitch" class, which you have more than one of.  If you target the"#myonoffswitch" instead, it being an id, only targets one thing and will only fire once.  I cleaned up your JS a bit too. Check it out, let me know what you think.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#myonoffswitch').on("click", function(){
    if($("#myonoffswitch").is(':checked') == false) {
        $('.container_slide_actu').animate({
        left : 0}, 700);
    }else{
      $('.container_slide_actu').animate({
        left : '-100%'}, 700);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body{
  margin:0;
}
.banner-site{
    width:100%;
    background-color:white !important;
    background-position:center !important;
    background-repeat:no-repeat !important;
    background-size:cover !important;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    height:350px;
    display:flex;
    align-items:center;
    margin-top:-15px;
    transition:all .7s;
    position:relative;
    border-bottom:1px solid white;
    border-top:1px solid white;
    overflow:hidden;
  }
  .banner-site:hover h1{
    color:white;
    border:2px solid white;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.9);
  }
  .banner-site:hover h1 a{
    color:white;
  }
  .banner-site a{
  color:black;
  text-decoration:none;
    transition:all .7s;
  }
  .banner-site .false-hover{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0);
    z-index:1;
    transition:all .7s;
  }
  .banner-site h1{
    text-align:center;
    border:2px solid #161416;
    color:#161416;
    margin:auto;
    padding:10px;
    border-radius:2px;
    font-family:'Cinzel';
    font-size:30px;
    font-weight:300;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 5px rgba(255,255,255,.9);
    transition:all .3s;
  }
  .banner-site .false-hover:hover{
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  }
  /*On/Off switch | ty https://proto.io/freebies/onoff/ */
.onoffswitch {
    position: absolute; width: 90px;
    -webkit-user-select:none; -moz-user-select:none; -ms-user-select: none;
    opacity:.5;/*à voir si on keep*/
    right:10px; bottom:15px;
    z-index:9999;
    display:block;
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox {
    display: none;
}
.onoffswitch-label {
    display: block; overflow: hidden; cursor: pointer;
    border: 2px solid #999999; border-radius: 20px; text-transform:uppercase;
}
.onoffswitch-inner {
    display: block; width: 200%; margin-left: -100%;
    transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:before, .onoffswitch-inner:after {
    display: block; float: left; width: 50%; height: 30px; padding: 0; line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 14px; color: white; font-family: 'Oswald', Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:before {
    content: "Home";
    padding-left: 10px;
    background-color: #000000; color: #FFFFFF;
}
.onoffswitch-inner:after {
    content: "News";
    padding-right: 10px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF; color: #000000;
    text-align: right;
}
.onoffswitch-switch {
    display: block; width: 25px; margin: 2.5px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0;
    right: 56px;
    border: 2px solid #999999; border-radius: 20px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-inner {
    margin-left: 0;
}
.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-switch {
    right: 0px;
}
.container_slide_actu{
  width:100%;
  height:350px;
  z-index:999;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:-100%;
  display:block;
}
#mavideo {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 350px;
  object-fit:cover;
}
/*look http://www.alsacreations.com/tuto/lire/1620-une-video-arriere-plan-sur-toute-la-page.html*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
  <title></title>

   <body>


   <div class="banner-site" style="background-image:url('https://media.senscritique.com/media/000009498078/1200/Lady_Vengeance.jpg')">
     <h1><a class="tdn cgrey" href="#" title="Retour à l'accueil de">Play it's evil?</a></h1>
     <div class="false-hover"></div>
    <!-- Button on/off à replace-->
     <div class="onoffswitch">
         <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" checked autocomplete="off">
         <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
             <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
             <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
         </label>
     </div>
   <div class="container_slide_actu">
    <video id="mavideo" controls autoplay muted loop="true">
     <source src="" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
   </div>
  </div>

   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>


 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Hi,

Thanks, it works good. I tried with the checked attribute technic but not with the animate method, you made my day, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I added `console.log('has nothere');` and `console.log('nothere not present');` only to make sure the *if* was working and noticed at the beginning that both the *if* and *else* conditions were being met on a single click.

Not sure what you are trying to accomplish yet but I moved the add/remove class lines inside an anonymous function to be executed once the animation has been completed.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

function switchButton(){
  console.log("coucou")
  $('.onoffswitch').click(function(){
    if($('.onoffswitch').hasClass('nothere')){
      console.log('has nothere');
        $('.container_slide_actu').animate({
        left : 0}, 700, function() {
                // Animation complete.
                $('.onoffswitch').removeClass('nothere');
            });
    }else{
        console.log('nothere not present');
      $('.container_slide_actu').animate({
        left : '-100%'}, 700, function() {
                // Animation complete.);
                $('.onoffswitch').addClass('nothere');
            });
       }
  });
}

switchButton();
});
```

Please try and let me know.